# How to add Checkbox Fields to User Accounts?

Tags: 8, users

Is it possible to add multi-choice checkbox fields to a Content Type or the fields of a User Type? Hoping it is possible to create the following when a User is registering for an account. They should be able to choose multiple check boxes when registering.

**Desired output in user registration form:**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="checkbox1" value="first-choice">
<label id="checkbox1-label" for="checkbox1">First Choice</label><br>

<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" name="checkbox2" value="second-choice">
<label id="checkbox2-label" for="checkbox2">Second Choice</label><br>

<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" name="checkbox3" value="third-choice">
<label id="checkbox3-label" for="checkbox3">Thrid Choice</label><br>
```

Comment: Yes this is possible. The user entity is fieldable.

Comment: Do I need to use PHP? Or can it be done by managing fields within the admin interface? What field would I use?

Comment: Yes, admin interface. Use a List field.

Comment: @crayden which version of drupal are you using? 7 or 8?

Comment: I am using Drupal 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add checkbox list from Account Settings

Go to  Configuration >> People >> Account settings - http://example.com/admin/config/people/accounts/fields

Add Field >> Add a new field of List(text)

[image]

Add options and select options as unlimited (for multiple select)

[image]

Save and go to Manage Form display (/admin/config/people/accounts/form-display) change the checkbox widget to checkboxes/radio buttons.

[image]

That's it you can see the check boxes in user account form like this

[image]